# Is there a way to fast forward using just_audio?

Tags: android, flutter, audio, mobile, just-audio

I'm using [just_audio](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio) and it works great.

But can't seem to find a way to fast-forward or rewind.

Update: It turns out just_audio is part of the [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package, using audio_service solved the problem for me.

Comment: I am also using the same package but I am not able to find an audio streaming position and complete audio duration...
can you please help?

Comment: I think that you need to use [audio_service](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service)

Answer (score 7):

`player.seek(Duration(seconds: player.position.inSeconds - 15));` rewind 15 second
`player.seek(Duration(seconds: player.position.inSeconds + 15));` forward 15 second'

```
 IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.replay_10,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      iconSize: 25,
      onPressed: () async {
        await player.seek(Duration(seconds: player.position.inSeconds - 15));
      },
    )`
```

the `player` comes from `AudioPlayer player`

Comment: aint working for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in fast-forward or rewind feature, but you can write a loop that seeks to `currentPosition + Duration(seconds: 10)` and then sleeps for 1 second, repeatedly. This is how it is implemented in the audio_service example, using a helper class similar to the following:

```dart
class Seeker {
  /// A reference to your just_audio player
  final AudioPlayer player;
  final Duration positionInterval;
  final Duration stepInterval;
  final Duration fileDuration;
  bool _running = false;

  Seeker(
    this.player,
    this.positionInterval,
    this.stepInterval,
    this.fileDuration,
  );

  start() async {
    _running = true;
    while (_running) {
      Duration newPosition = player.position + positionInterval;
      if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
      if (newPosition > fileDuration) newPosition = fileDuration;
      player.seek(newPosition);
      await Future.delayed(stepInterval);
    }
  }

  stop() {
    _running = false;
  }
}
```

To start fast-forwarding by jumping forward at 10 second intervals every 1 second, use:

```dart
      seeker = Seeker(player, Duration(seconds: 10),
          Duration(seconds: 1), mediaItem)
        ..start();
```

And stop fast-forwarding with:

```dart
seeker.stop();
```

To rewind, just pass in negative 10 seconds instead.